# Issue with ItemType Property in GridView?

Tags: entity-framework, entity

I have a problem with GridView ItemType Property :

when I set the ItemType property in the html the metadata of the entity that  set by

DataAnnotations like DisplayName,Validation are loaded and every thing work fine

but when I set the ItemType property  in the Page_Load event the MetaData of the entity are

not loaded and I do not know why this happened ?

thanks alot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution

I set the ItemType Property in the OnInit event of the gridview and it is working now